# Java (maven) using SSL with Shiro - https port plugin for Tomcat 7 not working

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ssl, shiro

I've created a keystore and placed it in a folder called "cert".
I used the code below in the pom.xml to listen for port number 8443 but it has no effect on the browser loading the page.  I assume shiro works because it successfully redirects me from port number 8080 to 8443.
I also don't get any errors which makes things harder.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
        <contextFile>${basedir}/WebContent/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
        <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
        <keystoreFile>${basedir}/certs/cert.jks</keystoreFile>
        <keystorePass>secret</keystorePass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't know if there is something missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [tomcat ssl docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), https is configured in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`.

As such believe you'd need to take a look there. I am not familiar with `shiro` but believe you'd need to check the `server.xml` configuration if you are using Tomcat.

Maven would be expected to read `pom.xml` and `shiro` plugin perhaps configures ssl for you but it ultimately needs to update the server.xml. Check that.

Comment: You are correct.  I was missing the connector for the 8443 port in the server.xml file